# How to upload/deploy jar file on Azure Web App using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There is generated Spring Boot jar file which can be accessed via URL (not git repo). How to upload jar file for deployment on Azure Web App using ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are looking for a manner to deploy a code package (jar/war) with ARM template. In order to do so, you will have to use the MsDeploy extension in your ARM template and use the dependsOn property to make sure your app is created before deploying the application. 
You may refer to below sample link: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/umbraco-webapp-simple/azuredeploy.json